# Unit test an action on UITextField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ocunit, ocmock

I have a simple if condition that, when met, adds a target to drop the keyboard when "Done" is tapped

```
- (void)addDoneWhenTrue:(UITextField *)input
{
    if (YES)
    {
        [input addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldFinished:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
    }
}

- (IBAction)textFieldFinished:(id)sender
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

I'm using OCMock and OCUnit on iOS5. How can I create a unit test that allows me to pass in a simple `UITextField` input and simulate tapping the done button on it to verify that `resignFirstResponder` does happen (or not)?

Comment: I think I can help you with your tests, but first, why are you adding this target/action? Why not just implement `textFieldShouldReturn:` with `if (theCondition) [self.textField resignFirstResponder];`

Comment: Interesting -not sure I had a real reason to use the implementation above (just wanted the DONE button on the basic keyboard to drop it on click so ... anything you have that is testable and does this works for me)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to mock it, and this target/action approach feels like a really roundabout way to get to what you want. As long as your controller is the `UITextField`'s delegate, `textFieldShouldReturn:` will be fired when the Return (or Done in this case) key is tapped.

```
#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate

-(void)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (someConditionThatDeterminesWhetherKeyboardShouldCollapse) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Then you can test calling `textFieldShouldReturn:` on your controller when your condition is and isn't met. If you want, you could also make sure your view has been loaded in the test case by calling `loadView`, and then assert that the text field's delegate is your controller, which will ensure the view is wired up correctly.

```
-(void)testDoneShouldCollapseKeyboard {
    [controller loadView];
    expect(controller.textField.delegate).to.beIdenticalTo(controller);

    id mockTextField = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:controller.textField];
    [[mockTextField expect] resignFirstResponder];
    controller.someConditionThatDeterminesWhetherKeyboardShouldCollapse = YES;

    [controller textFieldShouldReturn:controller.textField];

    [mockTextField verify];

    [[mockTextField reject] resignFirstResponder];
    controller.someConditionThatDeterminesWhetherKeyboardShouldCollapse = NO;

    [controller textFieldShouldReturn:controller.textField];

    [mockTextField verify];
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could clarify this a little more? I didn't directly set the delegate directly on this controller (only the target of the input but i'm not sure how to test this). Also if I call textFieldShouldReturn (but don't implement this ...) did I miss something? I only have what's shown above currently with textFieldFinished

Comment: Updated with sample code. If you want to handle the Done key, you need to set a delegate on the text field. The delegate is generally your controller.

Comment: When you say "when Done is tapped", you mean the bottom-right key on the keyboard, right?

Comment: yes -exactly (still trying to get my head around your awesome post above)

Comment: Take a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

Answer (score 0):

Surely you don't need to simulate clicking on a button as that's what `UIKit` is taking care of. You are concerned that when the `textFieldFinished:` method is called the right thing happens

**Disclaimer**

I've not used `OCMock` for a long time so this is an example just using the docs so it could very easily be slightly incorrect - hopefully someone can correct who has `OCMock` all setup.

```
id mock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[UITextField class]];

[[mock expect] resignFirstResponder];

[sut textFieldFinished:mock]; // sut = system under test - taken from your screen cast ;)

[mock verify];
```

Comment: I actually was looking for a way to do the input.click and then using ocmock assert the resignFirstResponder was invoked (using a partial mock). Was curious if anyone was able to do this because it would produce a higher level / less brittle unit test IMHO

Comment: Then that would be an integration test - which are generally more brittle than unit tests? I'm not sure I see the value in unit testing `UIKit` components. Looking a bit closer at your code, I'm wondering why are you not using the `UITextFieldDelegate` methods `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField`? Then if you must unit test you could make sure that at some point you are setting up the textField with the correct delegate object

Comment: We could certainly debate if unit/integration is correct in this case. What I can say is that I was looking for another way to assert this that was much less implementation specific and instead behavior specific. I write assertions like the one you mentioned over and over and the same thing hits me -if I was writing this test first with behavior in mind why wouldn't I assert that it drops the keyboard? Just asking as I always look to improve and this test (that I write over and over again) was making me feel as if I could do something better

Comment: I'm not sure there is a better way - you are testing your unit of code and hoping that the black box that is `UITextField` does indeed call it's delegate and then you are also hoping that `resignFirstResponder` will in fact remove the keyboard. So if everything is wired up correctly (this you can test) then the delegate method `textFieldDidEndEditing:` will be called and you can then test this.